Using proc_pidinfo with Swift
I would like to list all open files of a process. I could create this code so far:
struct ProcFileDescriptorInfo {
    var fd: Int32
    var path: String
}

func getFileDescriptors(pid: pid_t) -> [ProcFileDescriptorInfo] {
    var fds = [ProcFileDescriptorInfo]()
    let bufsize = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, nil, 0)
    guard bufsize > 0 else {
        print("Error: Failed to retrieve file descriptors for PID \(pid)")
        return []
    }
    
    let fdinfo = UnsafeMutablePointer<proc_fdinfo>.allocate(capacity: Int(bufsize))
    defer { fdinfo.deallocate() }
        
    let size = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, fdinfo, bufsize)
    guard size > 0 else {
        print("Error: Failed to retrieve file descriptors for PID \(pid)")
        return []
    }
    
    let count = Int(size) / MemoryLayout<proc_fdinfo>.size
    for i in 0..<count {
        let fd = fdinfo.advanced(by: i).pointee.proc_fd
        let type = fdinfo.advanced(by: i).pointee.proc_fdtype
        if type != PROX_FDTYPE_VNODE {
            continue
        }
        
        var vnodeInfo = vnode_fdinfowithpath()
        let vnodeInfoSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<vnode_fdinfowithpath>.size)
        let ret = proc_pidfdinfo(pid, fd, PROC_PIDFDVNODEPATHINFO, &vnodeInfo, Int32(vnodeInfoSize))
        if ret <= 0 {
            print("Error: Failed to retrieve vnode info for file descriptor \(fd) of PID \(pid)")
            continue
        }
        
        let path = withUnsafeBytes(of: &vnodeInfo.pvip.vip_path) { rawPtr in
            let ptr = rawPtr.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)
            return String(cString: ptr)
        }
        fds.append(ProcFileDescriptorInfo(fd: fd, path: path))
    }
    
    return fds
}

I opened Activity Monitor.app and I took the PID of the Preview.app. I then get a list, for example with the path to the FontCollections or to CoreImage. But I do not get a list with the open files. Why?
EDIT
I wrote this C-code with the helf of the internet to test:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/proc_info.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libproc.h>

#define MAX_BUF_SIZE 1024

void list_open_files(pid_t pid) {
    struct proc_fdinfo *fds;
    int buffer_size = 0;
    int num_fds = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, NULL, 0);
    
    if (num_fds <= 0) {
        perror("Failed to get file descriptors");
        return;
    }
    
    buffer_size = num_fds * sizeof(struct proc_fdinfo);
    fds = (struct proc_fdinfo *)malloc(buffer_size);
    if (!fds) {
        perror("Memory allocation failed");
        return;
    }
    
    num_fds = proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, fds, buffer_size);
    printf("%d file descriptors\n", num_fds);
    if (num_fds <= 0) {
        perror("Failed to get file descriptors");
        free(fds);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_fds; i++) {
        if (fds[i].proc_fdtype == PROX_FDTYPE_VNODE) {
            struct vnode_fdinfowithpath vnodeInfo;
            int bytesUsed = proc_pidfdinfo(pid, fds[i].proc_fd, PROC_PIDFDVNODEPATHINFO, &vnodeInfo, PROC_PIDFDVNODEPATHINFO_SIZE);
            if (bytesUsed == PROC_PIDFDVNODEPATHINFO_SIZE) {
                printf("Open file: %s\n", vnodeInfo.pvip.vip_path);
            }
        } else {
            printf("type: %d at %d\n", fds[i].proc_fdtype, i);
        }
    }
    
    free(fds);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = 67771;
    list_open_files(pid);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Somehow I get more file descriptors then in my Swift example (yes, it's using a different way and as I changed this in Swift, I became the same amount):
func getFileDescriptors(pid: pid_t) -> [ProcFileDescriptorInfo] {
    var fds = [ProcFileDescriptorInfo]()
    
    var numFds = Int(proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, nil, 0))
    if numFds <= 0 {
        print("Error: Failed to get file descriptors")
        return []
    }
    
    let bufSize = Int(numFds) * MemoryLayout<proc_fdinfo>.size
    let fdinfo = UnsafeMutablePointer<proc_fdinfo>.allocate(capacity: bufSize)
    
    numFds = Int(proc_pidinfo(pid, PROC_PIDLISTFDS, 0, fdinfo, Int32(bufSize)))
    let count = numFds
    
    print("\(count) filedescriptors")
    for i in 0..<numFds {
        let fd = fdinfo.advanced(by: i).pointee.proc_fd
        let type = fdinfo.advanced(by: i).pointee.proc_fdtype
        
        if type == PROX_FDTYPE_VNODE {
            var vnodeInfo = vnode_fdinfowithpath()
            let vnodeInfoSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<vnode_fdinfowithpath>.size)
            let ret = proc_pidfdinfo(pid, fd, PROC_PIDFDVNODEPATHINFO, &vnodeInfo, Int32(vnodeInfoSize))
            if ret <= 0 {
                print("Error: Failed to retrieve vnode info for file descriptor \(fd) of PID \(pid)")
                continue
            }
            
            let path = withUnsafeBytes(of: &vnodeInfo.pvip.vip_path) { rawPtr in
                let ptr = rawPtr.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)
                return String(cString: ptr)
            }
            fds.append(ProcFileDescriptorInfo(fd: fd, path: path))
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_ATALK {
            print("apple talk")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_SOCKET {
            print("socket")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_PSHM {
            print("pshm")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_PSEM {
            print("psem")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_KQUEUE {
            print("kqueue")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_PIPE {
            print("pipe")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_FSEVENTS {
            print("fsevents")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_NETPOLICY {
            print("netpolicy")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_CHANNEL {
            print("channel")
        } else if type == PROX_FDTYPE_NEXUS {
            print("nexus")
        } else {
            print("unkonwn \(type)")
        }
    }
    
    return fds
}

But still: The amount of the type PROX_FDTYPE_VNODE is the same and there I cannot find the open files. The rest of the descriptors are mostly of the type PROX_FDTYPE_ATALK.
If I use the command:
lsof -p 67771 -F n | wc -l
I get the number 339 in my case, the code above brings me back only 200. But even if I increase the for loop manually to 339, it's not working, because then the type of the node is not a VNODE anymore, I just get trash information.

One hunch is that some of the type involved here aren't correct, so your "total_size / item_size" calculations come up lower than they should be.

By the way, the relevant thing to divide by here is .alignment, not .size (which doesn't account for padding)

thanks for your help: I made an edit to my question

I think there's a mistake in the C code you're comparing against. The result of proc_pidinfo is the buffer size, not the number of elements. So e.g. buffer_size = num_fds * sizeof(struct proc_fdinfo) is wrong: buffer_size should be the result of proc_pidinfo, and you divide by the stride of  proc_fdinfo to get the num_fds. Compare: http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/19/getting-the-files-being-used-by-a-process-on-mac-os-x/

I'm fairly confident your first Swift code is correct. Are you sure Preview.app actually has the file open that you're thinking about? It's entirely possible that it just opened the file, read it, and closed it, and wouldn't have an FD for you to see listed here.

By the way, you clean this up pretty nicely if use a switch statement, and the Array.init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:) API. Check it out: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/661ea7fd85f1d60292ebaafce263293f
